# The second view is not updated if the main view is updated in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation, router

For navigation I decided to use routing.
And I have a problem if I have two views with the same data.
The first is the List.
The second is detailed information.
At the moment when the data is updated on the first screen, the view is also updated.
But if the user views the second view and the data is updated then the second screen is not updated.

How can I dynamically update the second view when the data is updated?

I use ObservedObject in main screen

```
@ObservedObject var router = Router<Views>()
    
     WindowGroup {
                NavigationStack(path: $router.paths){
                    RootScreenView()
                        .navigationDestination(for: Views.self){ destination in
                            ViewFactory.viewForDestination(destination)
                    }
               }
          }
```

This is my ViewFactory

```
enum Views: Hashable {
        case DetailView(order: OrderModel)
        // Any cases
    }
    
    enum ViewFactory {
        @MainActor
        @ViewBuilder
        static func viewForDestination(_ destination: Views) -> some View {
    
            case .DetailView(let order):
                DetailView(with: DetailViewModel(order: order))
    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    final class Router<T: Hashable>: ObservableObject {
        @Published var paths: [T] = []
        func push(_ path: T) {
            paths.append(path)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should never use `@ObservedObject` where you own the object -- it should always be `@StateObject`

Comment: Thank you. I try to da it but also not work.

Comment: I don't think it's the solution, but it's part of it

Comment: if I use NavigationLink for second view all work correctly when I use Router no work

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to centralise routing when its designed to be decentralised, i.e. `navigationDestination` is designed to go anywhere in the `View` data struct hierarchy.

Also, you shouldn't init objects in `body` like `DetailViewModel(order: order)` because it'll be re-init the next time `body` is called so essentially it's a memory leak. You need to use `@State` for your view data, pass down to child `View` as `let` for readonly or `@Binding` for read/write. `body` will be called whenever the data changes to you can init your child Views again with the new data and the UI will auto-update. Thus all of this is essentially is a view model already, if you try to reimplement this yourself in "view model" classes you'll run into problem after problem.

Comment: use navigationDestination looks like this will involve a complete overhaul of the app's navigation(